# How to customize browser webpush notification body & icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, service-worker

How can we make the browser notification `icon` and `body` dynamically customized based upon the `@challenge.image` and the `@challenge.description`?

[image]

I got the notification to pop up by clicking `webpush-button`, but only the `title` of the message is dynamically changing. How can I make it work for `body` and `icon` too?

**challenges/show.html.erb**

```
<script>
  $('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
      serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then((subscription) => {
        $.post('/push', {
          subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
          message: "<%= @challenge.name %>", # This works dynamically for the title, but how can I get message to also dynamically send body and icon so I can use <%= @challenge.image %> for icon and <%= @challenge.description %> for body?
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**push_notifications_controller**

```
class PushNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def push
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
  end
end
```

**application.js**

```
  if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js')
    .then(function(reg) {
       console.log('Service worker change, registered the service worker');
    });
  }
  // Otherwise, no push notifications :(
  else {
    console.error('Service worker is not supported in this browser');
  }

  // When serviceWorker is supported, installed, and activated,
  // subscribe the pushManager property with the vapidPublicKey
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: window.vapidPublicKey
    });
  });

  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    console.error("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
      }
    });
  }
```

**serviceworker.js.erb**

```
console.log('[Service Worker] Hello world!');

var CACHE_VERSION = 'v1';
var CACHE_NAME = CACHE_VERSION + ':sw-cache-';

function onInstall(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([

        // make sure serviceworker.js is not required by application.js
        // if you want to reference application.js from here
        '<%#= asset_path "application.js" %>',

        '<%= asset_path "application.css" %>',

        '/offline.html',

      ]);
    })
  );
}

function onActivate(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Activating!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
          // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
          // but remember that caches are shared across
          // the whole origin
          return cacheName.indexOf(CACHE_VERSION) !== 0;
        }).map(function(cacheName) {
          return caches.delete(cacheName);
        })
      );
    })
  );
}

// Borrowed from https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp
function onFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // try to return untouched request from network first
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      // if it fails, try to return request from the cache
      return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        // if not found in cache, return default offline content for navigate requests
        if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
          (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
          console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Fetching offline content", event);
          return caches.match('/offline.html');
        }
      })
    })
  );
}

self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  let title = (event.data && event.data.text()) || "Yay a message";
  let body = "We have received a push message";
  let icon = '/assets/default.png';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, { title,body, icon })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('install', onInstall);
self.addEventListener('activate', onActivate);
self.addEventListener('fetch', onFetch);
```

**serviceworker-companion.js**

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js', { scope: './' })
    .then(function(reg) {
      console.log('[Companion]', 'Service worker registered!');
    });
}
```

I implemented push via [serviceworker gem](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails), [webpush gem](https://github.com/zaru/webpush), [VAPID tutorial](https://rossta.net/blog/using-the-web-push-api-with-vapid.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view**

```
<%= content_tag(:button, "Foo", class: "webpush-button") %>

<script>
  $('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
      serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then((subscription) => {
        $.post('/push', {
          subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
          message: "<%= @challenge.name %>", 
          body: "<%= @challenge.why %>",
          icon: "/assets/default.png"
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**controller**

```
class PushNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def push
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: JSON.generate({ 
        title: params[:message],
        body: params[:body],
        icon: params[:icon]
        }),
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
  end
end
```

**js**

```
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  var data = event.data.json();
  let title = (event.data && data.title) || "Yay a message";
  let body =  (event.data && data.body) || "We have received a push message";
  let icon =  (event.data && data.icon) || "/assets/blue-astronaut.png";

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, { title,body, icon })
  )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event.data` object in the `self.addEventListener("push", (event)=> {...})`, has a method `json()`, that method convert to json the `event.data` value.

***This will works only if the sended data is in the proper json format.***

Here is an example how I'm using web push:

```
self.addEventListener("push", function onPush(event) {
  var data = event.data.json()
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.message.title, {
    body: data.message.body,
    icon: data.message.icon,
    actions: [ 
      { action: 'Button one', title: "Button one text" },
      { action: 'Button two', title: "Button two text" }
    ]
  }));
});
```

Here is a method from my user.rb model:

```
 def send_web_push(title: , body: )
    #  the web_push is a payload with I save to the user record,
    #  that's allow me to send web push with background worker. 
    payload = {
      endpoint: web_push['endpoint'], 
      keys: {
        auth: web_push['auth'],
        p256dh: web_push['p256dh'] 
      }
    }
    push = WebPush.new(payload)
    push.set_vapid_details(
      'mailto:support@awesomesupewebapp.com',
      Rails.application.secrets.web_push_public_key,
      Rails.application.secrets.web_push_private_key
    )
    # below is a `:message` key in json format
    push.send_notification({
      message: {
        title: title,                 
        body: body,                  
        icon: "/this_is_my_icon.png" 
      }
    }.to_json)
  end
```

I use some other ruby gem for web_push, but its common I assume. From that example you should see how is the body, title and icon keys can be changed.

Comment: Like that `user.send_web_push(title: 'Here is a title', body: 'Here is a body')`

Comment: I had show just an example, that's mean your code can be other. This is an example of actual working code in my project. I'm not your debugging tool or development IDE. Here is a gem which I'm use https://github.com/miyucy/web_push

Comment: The best _thanks_ that you can do, it is approve or upvote an answer. No need words, make a thing.